# Change value in div when click on button with jquery?

Tags: jquery

Hi
I have a div that I want to change some values in, when I click a button.

If I click on

```
<button id="image320x150">320 x 150</button>
```

then I want to change the width to 100 and the height value to 200 in the div.

and if I click on:

```
<button id="image320x200">320 x 200</button>
```

then I want to change the width to 50 and the height value to 100 in the div.

```
<div style="width:200px;height:287.5px;overflow:hidden;">
```

And I want the div to have the original values at first.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: .....what? The values in the buttons and the values in your buttons have no correlation, unless I'm missing something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
  $("#something").click(function () {
    $(#something2).css("width","100");
  });
</script>
```

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
$('#try-me').click(function() {
    $('#aDiv').css({width: '30px', height: '20px'})
})
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/UDvPR/

Answer (score 0):

I don't really got the logic but whatever.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var sizes = [{width:100,height:200},{width:50,height:100}];
function setSize(i){ $("#target").css(sizes[i]); }
</script>
<button id="image320x150" onclick="setSize(0);">320 x 150</button>
<button id="image320x200" onclick="setSize(1);">320 x 200</button>
<div id="target" style="width:200px;height:287.5px;overflow:hidden;"></div>
```

Comment: Anpher, great thanks a lot it works as it should!
But now another problem showed up, I need at the same time change the values here to the ones in sizes:
  var rx = 200 / coords.w;
  var ry = 287.5 / coords.h;

Comment: @Claes Gustavsson You need to change values where?

Comment: In two variable thats called rx and ry thats in another function.
var rx= 200/coords.w; and var ry=287.5/coords.h;

Comment: @Claes Gustavsson still nothing. var rx= 200/coords.w; and var ry=287.5/coords.h; <- variables defined. what else do you need?

Comment: When I click on eg the button id="image320x150" above I want to set the values in the variables aswell, something like

$('#image320x150').click(function() {
         $('var rx').("50");
         $('var ry').("100");

      });

Comment: @Claes Gustavsson you really should google for "javascript for noobs". just append this line to setSize function `rx = sizes[i].width; ry = sizes[i].height;`

Comment: Anpher, jepp your absolutly right, I should since I cant get it to work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
Jquery(document).ready(function() {

     jquery('#image320x150').click(function(){
         jquery('#div_id').css("width","100");
         jquery('#div_id').css("height","200");

      });

     jquery('#image320x200').click(function() {
         jquery('#div_id').css("width","50");
         jquery('#div_id').css("height","100");

      });
});
```

Comment: if your using jquery... keep it in the (document).ready... function... its bad practice to not use it.

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive, you need to use `jQuery`, not a variant of it, as they won't be defined.

Comment: its an example.  in most cases $ is going to be used anyway, or if its being done in an editor intelisense will take care of it.